# UI ideas on managing large set of text articles

Tags: android

I need to implement UI where user will be able to easily browse large set of text articles. I consider using TextSwitcher and onTouchEvent method implemented in order to have UI similar to browsing pictures in gallery. Do you have any ideas?(besides ListView) Would be grateful for any hints.

update: I want to show these articles randomly, so I do not want to let user browse among them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is not really a UI design problem but more of an application design problem.

On mobile devices, even counting tablets, you have very very small screen real estate.

The statement : "How can I browse large set of xx on a mobile with a 3 inches screen" is antinomical and the answer is  : "You shouldn't" :)

Give your user a very powerful search engine, organize your content in a tree of categories so that at the end of a branch or after a search there is no more than 10 to 20 results.
You can even go the evil root of : "Sorry your request generated more than 50 results, try to be more specific."

It will give you the following :

- -Great usability

  - Your content is now(was) organized and easy to reuse in other
    projects
  - Low bandwith usage (given this is web service based app)
  - Lower battery comsumption
  - No need to spend three days making your own custom UI component
    :D

Comment: Yahel thank you for your response, you are right. However I do not want to user let browse these articles, as I want to show them randomly, thats why I do not want to e.g. use ListView.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying : You want to show your items in a random order ? Then to keep it simple, I would display 25 random items and add a refresh button that says : "click here to generate a new selection". As for the use of listView, you could simply use a Gallery view ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html )

Comment: Thank you for interest Yahel. Well that is what I actually did, I just implemented onClick button in order to set new text. I hold these articles in string-array in xml file, which I pass to string table. I actually wonder is it not too expensive to hold them all in string table?

Comment: Depending on the number and the size of the text, i'd go for a database which would give you a nice cursor (managed) to play with without worrying about performance, memory and battery usage. I'd feed my gallery adapter with this cursor.